# QQuickWidget "closed" signal

Tags: qt, qt5, signals-slots, qqmlcomponent

What signal does it tell me when the QQuickWidget closes?

For example I wrote the following code :

```
QQuickWidget *view = new QQuickWidget;
view->setSource(QUrl::fromLocalFile("main.qml"));
view->show();
```

I have an `ApplicationWindow` in the `main.qml` file and I want to execute some code right after the qml window gets closed.

Comment: What do you mean by *after the Application Window item in one Qml file has finished up its execution*?

Comment: @eyllanesc I mean after the window gets closed.

Comment: Then you should say: What signal does it tell me when the QQuickWidget closes? in addition to providing a [mre]

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to implement a Helper that is injected into QML and notifies us when the window is closed:

```cpp
class Helper: public QObject{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    using QObject::QObject;
Q_SIGNALS:
    void closed();
};
```

```cpp
Helper *helper = new Helper;
QObject::connect(helper, &Helper::closed, [](){
   qDebug() << "closed";
});

QQuickWidget *view = new QQuickWidget;
view->rootContext()->setContextProperty("helper", helper);
view->setSource(QUrl::fromLocalFile("main.qml"));
view->show();
```

```
ApplicationWindow {
    // ...
    onClosing: helper.closed()
}
```

Comment: Why do I get the error "C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations" for the "QObject::connect()" line ? I've included <QObject> and also added Q_OBJECT macro  as in your answer.